How to use Cauchy Schwarz Inequality for proving a Metric in the Functional space.
The question is as follows:

Show that the set $[a,b]$ of all real valued continuous functions defined on the
closed interval $[a,b]$ with function defined by $d(f,g)$, is a metric space.
$$d(f,g) = \sqrt{\int^a_b[f(x) - g(x)]^2dx}$$

I know that to show that the function $d(f,g)$ is a metric the axioms M1 - M4 must be satisfied.
However, I was able to show M1 - M3. My confusion lies in M4 when using the triangle inequality.
I also know I have to use Cauchy Schwarz inequality for integrals given the question but, not entirely sure how to prove the last metric.
I know that the inequality is as follows:
$${\lvert[\int^a_bf(x)g(x) dx]\rvert} \leq \sqrt{\int^b_a[f(x)]^2dx} \sqrt{\int^b_a[g(x)]^2dx}$$
I know it has to map to the triangular inequality which considers the distance between three functions with the addition of $h(x)$.
Given the following:
$$d(f,g) \leq d(f,h) + d(h,g)$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Don't use MathJax to type text.

@ArturoMagidin sorry about that.

Are you sure the definition of $d(f, g)$ is correct? Wouldn't integration from b to a of a nonnegative function lead to a negative value, causing a negative value under the root?

@BobTheThird the function is defined correctly, also the difference between both of the functions is sqaured from the defined metric so i am assuming it would be positive in all cases. Well $\geq 0$.

I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't the total value of the integral be negative, since you're integrating from a bigger value to a smaller one? I thought that $\int_a^b .dx = -\int_b^a .dx$

I dont think so given the fact your integrating from bigger value wont the resultant of the integral be defined based on the nature of the function which affects the area under graph. However, to clear this issue up, it is assumed that the first three axions for the metric holds and so it would mean, that the function would produce a value $\geq 0$.

$$ ||f|| = \sqrt{\int_a^bf^2(x)dx} $$
We want to show
$$ ||f + g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g|| $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\int_a^b (f(x) + g(x))^2dx} \leq \sqrt{\int_a^b f^2(x) dx} + \sqrt{\int_a^b g^2(x) dx}$$
$$ \Leftarrow \int_a^b (f(x) + g(x))^2 dx \leq \int_a^b f^2(x) dx + 2 \cdot \sqrt{(\int_a^b f^2(x) dx) (\int_a^b g^2(x)dx)} \; + \int_a^b g^2(x) dx$$
Now:
$$ \int_a^b (f(x) + g(x))^2 dx = \int_a^b f^2(x)dx + 2\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx + \int_a^bg^2(x)dx$$
Combined with the previous inequality, we're only left needing to show that
$$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq \sqrt{(\int_a^b f^2(x) dx) (\int_a^b g^2(x)dx)} $$
which is precisely the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
At this point:
$$ d(f, g) = ||f-g|| = ||f+h-h+g|| \leq ||f-h|| + ||h-g|| = d(f, h) + d(h, g)$$

Thank you for the guidance. I now have a better understanding of how to use this inequality.
